# How to edit the button that toggled bootstrap modal with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have some buttons, that toggle the same same bootstrap modal.

What I'd like to achieve, is when I click on the **Edit toggler** button inside the modal, say the background of the button that toggled it, would change to red for example.

So if **Show modal 2** toggled it, by clicking **Edit toggler**, the background of **Show modal 2** would change to red.

Or if it was **Show modal 3** that toggled the modal, then it's background would change, and so on

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toplist.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" id="toggler1" class="btn btn-primary toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Show modal 1
</button>
<button type="button" id="toggler2" class="btn btn-primary toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Show modal 2
</button>
<button type="button" id="toggler3" class="btn btn-primary toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Show modal 3
</button>
<button type="button" id="toggler4" class="btn btn-primary toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Show modal 4
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      This is a modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit toggler</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a unique identifier to the button, for example. #id="edit-toggler"... Then just simply:

```
$("#edit-toggler").on('click', function(){
    $('#show-modal-2').toggleClass("red");
});
```

Css:

```
.red{
    background-color: red
}
```

I would suggest this approach, it's easier to modify and maintain. Hardcoding css attributes and values into Jquery is not very useful :)

Comment: That's not what I meant. I'd like to change the background of the button that toggled the modal by clicking the "Edit Toggler" button inside the modal, not by clicking the toggler button itself

Comment: you can specify which element you would like to modify when clicking a certain button. I updated the answer, I hope I got it right.